# Recognizing iOS file packages (in Simulator and Finder)

Tags: ios, finder, uti

I am trying to use file packages for an iOS app be defining an UTI type. After googling and looking at the entries in Xcode.plist, I tried a few things but kept running into problems. My app creates a few test documents and then tries to read those files with my custom UTI.

If I don't specify "LSItemContentTypes", then finder correctly sees them as packages. But then mdls returns "dyn.longstring" as kMDItemContentType.

If I do specify "LSItemContentTypes", then the kMDItemContentType is correct. But finder sees it as a folder.

In both cases the UTI I get via

```
[url getResourceValue:&UTI
forKey:NSURLTypeIdentifierKey
error:nil];
```

is incorrect. It either returns "dyn.longstring" or "public.folder". My app doesn't load these files because of the incorrect UTI. I could rewrite this but want to do it the right way with UTI's.

I defined an iOS file package as document type and exported UTI type as can be seen below. What am I overlooking?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>tdp</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MyFilePackage</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>reverse.dns.ios.package</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
        <true/>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename.extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>tdp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>reverse.dns.ios.package</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.package</string>
            <string>public.composite-content</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Was having a similar issue, including the UTI showing up as "dyn.longstring". Seems like the fix was to remove CFBundleTypeExtensions attribute (which is deprecated). This combination in the info.plist worked for me:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My App Name</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>my.content.type</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.package</string>
            <string>public.composite-​content</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My App Name</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>my.content.type</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>myextension</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```